# How can I add html tag to the content div of Quill text editor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, quill, ngx-quill

I have a form with quill text editor.

```
<quill-editor [modules]="quillConfig" (onEditorCreated)="getEditorInstance($event)"></quill-editor>
```

I have an image gallery in a modal, which is filled with my images, and I would like that, if I select an image from modal put the img tag after the text in the editor.

This is the code of one image what I want to add:

```
<div class="news-image-box">
  <img src="${image.path}" alt="${image.description}">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9"><p>${image.description}</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 news-image-credit"><p>${image.credit}</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the contenteditable div of Quill (which is the div for my text and it has "ql-editor" css class) is generated, so I can't give a local reference for using @ViewChild... (or I don't know how)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor')[0].innerHTML += imageElement;
```

I tried to get the content of "ql-editor" div by a sample getElementsByClassname and just added my img tag to it, but the angular throws this error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
at Scroll.update (quill.js:4329)
at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (quill.js:7118)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:151)
at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (zone.js:129)
```

I works with just a string btw...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor')[0].innerHTML += 'something';
```

Comment: Have you tried turning the element into a string before appending to the innerHTML?

Comment: Yes, it was the same situation, or added to it between " " inside a <p> tag :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with ngModel, it is clearly mentioned in documentation.
Reference:
[ngx-quill git Repo](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill)

Example Snippet:

```
 <quill-editor [(ngModel)]="productDetail"  [style]="{border: '0px'}"></quill-editor>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works almost perfectly! :) Finally the image is added but without div tags... I found the sanitize option in documentation but how can I use it? 
I tried this way:

`<quill-editor [(ngModel)]="contentText" 
                  [sanitize]="false"
                  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                  [modules]="quillConfig"
                  (onEditorCreated)="getEditorInstance($event)"></quill-editor>`

... but it throws this error :
`ng: Can't bind to 'sanitize' since it isn't a known property of 'quill-editor'.

Comment: Which version of quil you are using?

Comment: Sanitization only support in V3.3.0 and After.

Reference: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/198

Comment: I have "ngx-quill": "^4.1.0", and "quill": "^1.3.6". 
I think this is up-to-date.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this, That will be make this more easy to debug.

Comment: I don't know, can I install quill on stackblitz? Because without it, you can't run it, so I think it's not a big help. :D

Comment: I created an example for this in stackblitz


https://ngx-quill-wytq8d.stackblitz.io

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much your help! I modified your code. You can see if you click the button the image will be added, but without the divs...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill-dxmifr

Comment: I don't get the query now, here what do want me to do now? Can you explain that more clear?

Comment: I would like to add my divs with css classes under your image if I click the button. But the editor is adding only just img tag without my div container.

Comment: For that kinda interpolation you need to use [(innerHtml)].

Comment: I have modified the stackblitz, But image size will be an issue if you use innerhtml

Comment: Oh thanks! I have only one problem with this, how can I put the [(innerHtml)] binding to the "textarea" div. Because now the image is replacing the textarea now :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to add a `img` tag inside your `quill-editor`.

Modifying the `Element.innerHTML` property is a good method if you want to do this but is a bit complicated. It exists simplier method to do that like `Element.insertBefore()` or `Element.append()`.

You can use them like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor')[0].append(imageElement);
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor')[0].insertBefore(imageElement, null);
```

If you really want to use the `Element.innerHTML`, I invite you to see [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML) about this property.

Hope this helps

Edit: Grammar

Comment: Thanks your answer, but the problem with this solution is that the html tags added like string, so when I read it from DB it won't be html tags but string in a <p> tag. I used [innerHtml] of course.